# If i had a <search input> not <account/password input>, do i need to use mysql_real_escape_string?

Tags: php, mysql

If i had a search input not account/password input, do i need to use mysql_real_escape_string?
could be sql injection?? $sql just select where limit row

```
<input type="text" name="search">

include"set.php";
$search=$_POST["search"];
if(strlen($search)) >= $min_length){
    $sql="select * from $tbl where subject or content like '%search%';";
    ..  
}
```

(mysql: subject and content both 'text' type)

if i need to use, i try this but doesnt work.

```
include"set.php";
$search=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["search"]);
if(strlen($search)) >= $min_length){
    $sql="select * from $tbl where subject or content like '%search%';";
    ..
    if(mysql_num_rows($query)>0){
        while ($list= mysql_fetch_array($query)){
            $subject=$list[subject];
            $content=$list[content];
            $...=$list[...];
            print "subject: $subject, ....";
        }
    }
    else{
         print "no results";
    }
}
else{
print "minimum length is". $min_length;
}
```

Comment: your input is named `seach` and you're getting `$_post['search']` which should be `$_POST` btw

Comment: [The Great Escapism (Or: What You Need To Know To Work With Text Within Text)](http://kunststube.net/escapism/)

Comment: Escaping the user input IS ALWAYS necessary measure against SQL injection attacks, cross-site request forgeries, broken XML, although it is not enough by itself.

Comment: You should escape **ALL** user inputted data. But not with `mysql_real_escape_string` - it's deprecated. Use `MySQLi` or `PDO` instead!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A. It should be `$_POST` not `$_post` variable name are case sensitive in PHP

B. `mysql_**` Depreciated use [mysqli_real_escape_string](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php) instead

FROM PHP DOC

> Use of this extension is discouraged. Instead, the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extension should be used. See also MySQL: choosing an API guide and related FAQ for more information. Alternatives to this function include:

C. Its always better to design a search form with `$_GET` instead so that the URL can easily be saved

Example

```
$search = filter_var($_GET["search"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING , FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_LOW | FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_HIGH);
if($search && strlen($search) > 3)
{
    $search = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $search);
    $sql = sprintf("SSELECT * FROM %s where subject or content like '%s';",$tbl,"%s" . $search ."%s");
}
```

D. You would never trust user input and aways validate and filter all the time

Comment: thanks but after i add mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["search"]) , i don't know why the code doesn't work, can't search

Comment: Ok you can try `var_dump($_REQUEST['search'])` and tell me if you got anything

Comment: i edit the article post original code.  and i try var_dump($_REQUEST['search'])  got minimum length is 2 NULL (no matter what length i type)

Comment: why? if remove mysql_real_escape_string() code can work print what i want, but var_dump shows null too

Comment: Put the `var_dump($_REQUEST['search'])` before `mysql_real_escape_string` and tell me what you get

Comment: i got string(3) "tes"minimum length is 2

Comment: string(2) "te" minimum length is 2

Comment: Ok lets do this .. add you full code to pastebin .. i would look at it editit and that should work

Comment: @user1575921 So many thing where wrong .. even your SQL .. you can try this http://pastebin.com/UFu3ynzK

Comment: @Baba still get  this string(7) "content" minimum length is 2

Comment: MAMP PHP 5.4.4 / phpMyadmin 3.5.1  / Database client version: libmysql - 5.5.25

Comment: Use http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php `mysql_real_escape_string` is depreciate and might be very unstable in PHP version 5.4

Comment: @Baba what version are you using??

Comment: 5.3 & 5.4 but i don't use  `mysql_real_escape_string` because it no longer  supported in PHP

Comment: You need to use the latest version ... already given you the link .. they are different .. the one you are using starts with `mysql_` they link i gave you starts with `mysqli_` .. Please notice the `i` differences http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php

Comment: i find the answer- MySQL connection is required before using mysql_real_escape_string() , now it works!

Comment: Cool am glad i was able to help

Answer (score 3):

You need to use prepared statements not escaping (yes all the time).

Answer (score 1):

You need `$_POST` and `$search`:

```
$search=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["search"]);
```

and

```
$sql="select * from $tbl where subject or content like '%".$search."%';";
```

and yes, every time your should escape any input by the user, no matter what.

Comment: thanks but after i add mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["search"]) , i don't know why the code doesn't work, can't search

Comment: what does `$search` look like after you add mysql_real_escape_string ?

Comment: I told you, it's `$search` and not `search`, look at my answer

Comment: , before add mysql_real_escape_string- '%.$search%' can work '%".$search."%' can't work. after add- '%".$search."%' can't work too